# How to update multiple formula arrays in Worksheet without Control+Shift+Enter?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am using an array formula for around 1000+ rows:

```
=SUM(N(FREQUENCY(IF(($B$2:$B$21=G8)*($C$2:$C$21="v1")*($D$2:$D$21="f"),$E$2:$E$21),$E$2:$E$21)>0))
```

But I have to press `Control+Shift+Enter` for each row.

I tried to avoid it by using vba code:

```
Dim rngFormulas           As Range
Dim rngCell               As Range
Dim lngCalcMode           As Long

On Error Resume Next
Set rngFormulas = Sheets("Overall Test Summary").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not rngFormulas Is Nothing Then
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        lngCalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With
    For Each rngCell In rngFormulas.Cells
        If LCase$(Left$(rngCell.Formula, 9)) <> "=iferror(" Then
            If rngCell.HasArray Then
                With rngCell.CurrentArray
                    .FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(" & Mid$(.FormulaArray, 2) & ",0)"
                End With
            Else
                With rngCell
                    .Formula = "=IFERROR(" & Mid$(.Formula, 2) & ",0)"
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Next rngCell
    With Application
        .Calculation = lngCalcMode
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
```

I am getting error in line:

```
.FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(" & Mid$(.FormulaArray, 2) & ",0)"
```

Is there a way to avoid pressing `Control+Shift+Enter` to update formulas in my sheet

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav `Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error`

Comment: Does it work without the `CurrentArray` and is `"=IFERROR(" & Mid$(.FormulaArray, 2) & ",0)"` giving you what you want before hand?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav No it does not work